# how to pass arguments to function and use these arguments in macro function inside it

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I want to do something like that

```
#define GREATER_THAN_ZERO(a) a>0? 1:0
```

and use this macro inside another function like that

```
void test(int x)
{  if (GREATER_THAN_ZERO(x) == 1) printf("more than zero");
   else printf("less than zero");
}
```

But when I use test function it always prints "less than zero"
NOTE: this is an example not the real case but I want to do something like that (use macro inside a function)
Can anyone help me please?
EDIT
I have configuration file like that

```
 #define LED_u8_MODE_0          LED_u8_REVERSE
 #define LED_u8_MODE_1          LED_u8_NORMAL
```

and in program I have a macro function

```
#define LED_u8_GET_MODE(LED_u8_INDX)        (LED_u8_INDX == 0)? LED_u8_MODE_0: \
(LED_u8_INDX == 1)? LED_u8_MODE_1: \
(LED_u8_INDX == 2)? LED_u8_MODE_2: \
(LED_u8_INDX == 3)? LED_u8_MODE_3: 800
```

then I use it inside this function

```
    void LED_voidSetLedOnWithIndx(u8 Copy_u8LedIndx)
{
    if(LED_u8_GET_MODE(Copy_u8LedIndx) == LED_u8_NORMAL)
    {
        DIO_voidSetPinValue(Copy_u8LedIndx, DIO_u8_HIGH);
    }
    else //if(LED_u8_GET_MODE(Copy_u8LedIndx) == LED_u8_REVERSE)
    {
        DIO_voidSetPinValue(Copy_u8LedIndx, DIO_u8_LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal code sample that exhibits the quoted issue and readers can use to replicate it. And if that's not your real case, give a real one that isn't completely silly. The macro you cite is far worse than just writing `thing > 0` and will infuriate readers of your code. Also, why the `? 1 : 0`? You know that already returns a boolean, right?

Comment: the real case is something like this example I want to use a macro that return 1 or 0 inside a function that I give the parameters in the run time

Comment: Show a minimal code sample that exhibits the quoted issue and readers can use to replicate it. Right now, we have only an incomplete fragment and your statement that it causes a problem, with no evidence of how the problematic behaviour is produced. We could go and write our own tests to prove or disprove what you said, but that's not our job.

Comment: @underscore_d Boolean->Integer->Boolean again with `==1`!

Comment: Comparison operators in C are guaranteed by the standard to return either 0 or 1 anyway, so the ternary operator is for nothing...

Comment: Safe macros should always put the arguments into parentheses, as well as the whole macro should be, so: `GTZ(a) ((a)>0?1:0)` or simply (consider my previous comment!): `GTZ(a) ((a)>0)`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I have no idea what you're talking about. No `== 1` is required; the `>` operator already returns a result of `0` or `1` that is guaranteed to behave correctly in any boolean context, and comparing explicitly to some value for booleans is discouraged by all good coding styles I've seen.

Comment: Albeit my first comment, always prefer comparing `!= 0` with boolean semantics - or even better: just leave the comparison out entirely (`if(GTZ(x))`);

Comment: @underscore_d I am not trying to justify OPs code. I am saying just as you said the `?1:0` is unnecessary, there is also an unnecessary `==1` because without that too, the meaning would be the same.

Comment: @MarioSonlord Please don't paste this code in a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Ah yeah, my bad!

Comment: @MarioSonlord And where exactly do you now use the macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem with the code you posted, but you mentioned it's not the real case, and I do have an idea of the problem.

The expression is not being associated as you intended.  When expanded, the expression is:

```
x>0? 1:0 == 1
```

which groups as:

```
x>0? 1:(0 == 1)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
x>0? 1:0
```

This still works as intended.  But if you instead had:

```
if (GREATER_THAN_ZERO(x) == 0)
```

then you would end up with:

```
x>0? 1:0 == 0
```

or:

```
x>0? 1:(0 == 0)
```

which is always 1.

There are two fundamental problems with the macro definition:  (1) it isn't protecting its argument from mis-association, and (2) it isn't protecting the result from mis-association.

The proper way to write it would be:

```
#define GREATER_THAN_ZERO(a) ((a) > 0 ? 1 : 0)
```

The parentheses around `(a)` allow you to pass an expression as the argument without worrying about it being re-associated. The parentheses around the entire macro body allow you to use the macro in an expression without it being re-associated.

In this particular case, the `?:` operator is redundant, since `n > 0` always returns either 0 or 1, so you could just use:

```
#define GREATER_THAN_ZERO(a) ((a) > 0)
```

with identical results.

Similarly, the comparison of the result with `1` serves no purpose and suggests that something unusual is going on.  It is much more natural to simply write:

```
if (GREATER_THAN_ZERO(x))
```

This implicitly tests to see if it's non-zero.  Remember, `if (n)` is equivalent to `if (n != 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Too large for a comment, so as answer: I recommend a different formatting (with parentheses adjusted, though):

```
#define LED_u8_GET_MODE(LED_u8_INDX)  \
    (                                 \
        (LED_u8_INDX) == 0            \
        ? (LED_u8_MODE_0)             \
        : (LED_u8_INDX) == 1          \
            ? (LED_u8_MODE_1)         \
            : (LED_u8_INDX) == 2      \
                ? (LED_u8_MODE_2)     \
                : (LED_u8_INDX) == 3  \
                    ? (LED_u8_MODE_3) \
                    : 800             \
    )
```

Or do you disagree that this is easier to read?

Still, those many ternary operators are difficult to read and handle, I'd rather consider replacing the entire macro with an inline function:

```
inline int ledGetMode(int index)
    // (if need be, adjust parameter and return value types appropriately)
{
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            return LED_u8_MODE_0;
        // ...
        default:
            return 800;
    }
}
```

Looks much cleaner and should, as inline, not have any overhead over the macro...

The main advantage, though, is that you simply skip any trouble with bad association of parameters or result and with multiple evaluation of the parameters!